# How many clr_optimization services are healthy?

Tags: windows-7

The performance of my Windows OS has been going downhill for quite some time. I finally decided to look into it and I found four running clr_optimization processes. I googled for what those are and they seem legit. I just don't understand why  I need four of those. I understand one is for 32bit, one for 64 bit, but why do I need v2.0 and v4.0. The v4.0 are still running, after 45 minutes of uptime. Is that normal? Do those create a lot of disc I/O? Apart from those I don't see anything I could blame my slow OS on.

Answer (score 4):

In .Net (a programming platform by Microsoft), the runtime versions (2.0 vs 4.0) are completely separate, and do not generally interoperate without extra work. No surprise that each would need it's own set of optimizers. For each version of the platform, 32 and 64 optimization is quite different, so I don't think it's unreasonable to have 4 copies of `clr_optimization` running.

I've not seen the `clr_optimization.exe` process that you speak of on my machine, so I can't offer specifics on its expected behavior.

Comment: Google knows those run at system boot, but stop relatively quickly. Mine, however, seem to have a lot to do ...

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provided 2 blog posts about what the optimizer does and how to speed this up:

**Wondering why mscorsvw.exe has high CPU usage? You can speed it up**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/06/wondering-why-mscorsvw-exe-has-high-cpu-usage-you-can-speed-it-up.aspx

**Got a need for speed? .NET apps start faster.**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/06/got-a-need-for-speed-net-apps-start-faster.aspx

And the .net 2.0 version should be disabled by the 4.x installer. Even if you optimize .net 2.0 DLLs, the 4.x version is used. So you should only see 2 instances.

In Windows 8, MS moved them into scheduled tasks which run when the PC is idle.

Answer (score -3):

clr_optimization is a process that you only see running when you are trying to access network. IE a datastore or shared folder. It will lauch a 32 bit and 64 bit for each time you try to access a network resource.

Comment: Yeah, no. It’s exactly as written by the others: This service precompiles .NET assemblies. It has absolutely nothing to with network access or datastores or shared folder or whatnot.